# XSD - attribute restriction ignored when validating

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am having issues trying to test the below xsd against the below xml files. Are my tools bad, or is my xsd not functioning in a predictable way?

Software tested:

- xmllint (using libxml version 20707)
- XML Copy Editor 1.2.0.6

Expected results:

- test.xml validates
- test-bad.xml fails validation due to malformed account attribute in domain tag

Oberved results:
 - test.xml validates
 - test-bad.xml validates

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "configuration.dtd">
<configuration  timestamp="2011-03-23T20:16:57.222" version="2.2" xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/api/2.2 configuration.xsd">
    <domain account="4af17ss66f-c841-4b97-a94a-edd7a012176" >
    </domain>
</configuration>
```

test-bad.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "configuration.dtd">
<configuration  timestamp="2011-03-23T20:16:57.222" version="2.2" xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/api/2.2 configuration.xsd">
    <domain account="totally invalid account" >
    </domain>
</configuration>
```

configuration.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="EN" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/api/2.2">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="domain"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:normalizedString" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" fixed="2.2"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="domain">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="account" type="uid" use="required">
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="uid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="36"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

configuration.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT configuration (domain)>
<!ATTLIST configuration
            timestamp           CDATA #IMPLIED
            version             CDATA #FIXED "2.2"
            xmlns               CDATA #IMPLIED
            xmlns:xsi           CDATA #IMPLIED
            xsi:schemaLocation  CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT domain ANY>
<!ATTLIST domain account CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you've accidentally defined two different `element`s with the name "domain".

This defines one, which can occur only inside `configuration`:

```
    <xs:element name="domain"/>
```

And this defines the other, which can only occur as a root element (you can see this if you remove the `configuration` element and have `domain` as the root - it won't validate anymore):

```
<xs:element name="domain">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="account" type="uid" use="required">
      </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Since the first definition doesn't say anything about its attributes, in your sample document the attribute "account" on your `domain` element is valid with any type.

To define only one element, the best way is to make the `element` definition you have into a `complexType`, and refer to that (the other alternative is to move all the `complexType` stuff inside the first `domain` deinfition):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/api/2.2" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="EN" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/api/2.2">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="domain" type="domain"/> <!-- changed here -->
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:normalizedString" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:token" fixed="2.2"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="domain"> <!-- and here -->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="account" type="uid" use="required">
      </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="uid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="36"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Two more comments: (1) your test.xml is invalid! :) (2) you shouldn't really be using DTDs if you have a schema, you're just repeating yourself, and DTDs are nowhere near as powerful.

Comment: Using name="domain" rather than ref="domain" is a common error, and one that often goes unnoticed unless you test your schemas carefully. The Saxon schema processor [advertisement!] gives you a warning if you make this mistake.

Comment: xmllint blew up and told me that test.xml is invalid without that I'll be spending more time fiddling with that. @Michael Kay, I hear that program is the best thing since sliced bread. When I think of XML, I think of SAXON. [/advertisement!]